# How to save a persistent value for application access across multiple runs?

Tags: c++

As the title states, I would like to store a variable (which will always be an positive integer < 10,000) for my application to access and process as needed across multiple runs.

My current implementation simply saves the value to a file, in the current directory, and then reads it in when needed.

```cpp
#include<fstream>

int x = 5;
std::ofstream write_file(file_handle);
write_file << value;
write_file.close();
```

However, I'm not too keen on the idea of having an orphaned text file if the user decides to place the `.exe` on their desktop.

So, what other options do I have to store the value?

I'm primarily concerned with Windows 8+.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want to store a value in the Windows Registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using a file, but you don't have to (and should not) store it in the same folder as the `.exe` file, as it may not work depending on *where* the `.exe` is located (for instance, non-admins can't write to `Program Files`).

Windows sets aside special folders in the user's profile just for application-generated data, so you should store the file in one of those folders instead. Use the Win32 [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) function to discover where those special folders are located, and then you should create a sub-folder for your application's use (you can even use [`SHGetFolderPathAndSubDir()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathandsubdirw) for that purpose).

For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>

#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

fs::path pathToMyValueFile()
{
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (SHGetFolderPathAndSubDirW(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, L"MyApp", szPath) != S_OK) {
        throw ...;
    }
    return fs::path(szPath) / L"value.dat";

    /* alternatively:

    if (SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath) != S_OK)
        throw ...;

    fs::path folder = fs::path(szPath) / L"MyApp";
    fs::create_directory(folder);

    return folder / L"value.dat";
    */
}

...

int value = 0;
std::ifstream read_file(pathToMyValueFile());
if (read_file.is_open()) {
    read_file >> value;
    read_file.close();
}

...

int value = 5;
std::ofstream write_file(pathToMyValueFile());
if (write_file.is_open()) {
    write_file << value;
    write_file.close();
}
```

In the future, if the user ever uninstalls your app, be sure to delete that subfolder.

---

Otherwise, you can store the value in the [Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry) instead.  Create a new key for your application under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software` as needed, and then you can create values inside that key.

For example:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

int readMyValue()
{
    int value;

    HKEY hKey;
    LSTATUS lRes = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\MyApp", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
    if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD size = sizeof(value);
        lRes = RegQueryValueExA(hKey, "Value", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&value, size);
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (lRes != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            throw ...;

        value = 0;
    }

    return value;
}

void saveMyValue(int value)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LSTATUS lRes = RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\MyApp", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
    if (lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD size = sizeof(value);
        lRes = RegSetValueExA(hKey, "Value", 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }

    if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw ...;

    /* alternatively:

    if (RegSetKeyValueA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\MyApp", "Value", REG_DWORD, &value, sizeof(value)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        throw ...;
    */
}

...

int value = readMyValue();

...

int value = 5;
saveMyValue(value);
```

If your app is uninstalled later, be sure to delete the Registry key.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the first implementation, "'SHGetFolderPathAndSubDirW' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'SHGetFolderPathW'?", I'm currently compiling with the following options: g++ -std=c++17 -lshlwapi

Comment: No, I really meant `SHGetFolderPathAndSubDirW()`, I even linked to the documentation for it. But, if you can't get it working, you can use  `SHGetFolderPathW()` instead, you'll just have to create the subfolder manually. I have updated my example.

Comment: I was able to get it working with SHGetFolderPathW().  Sorry, I'm still trying to learn the windows API. I'm still not sure why I can't get the first command to work, but I'll do more research and if I find out, I'll update with the problem.

Comment: You are probably using an outdated Win32 SDK, or you don't have your project configured to target XP+.

Comment: I was able to look into it further, you were right, my SDK was out of date. Thanks again for your help.